# Duplicating custom nodes in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

As far as I understand, duplicating nodes in JavaFX should be done with the `Duplicator.duplicate` function.

It works fine when duplicating nodes whose types are included in JavaFX library, for example

```
def dup = Duplicator.duplicate(Rectangle{x:30 y:30 width:100 height:100});
dup.translateX = 10;
insert dup into content;
```

would insert a black rectangle to the scene.

However if I define a new class in the following way:

```
class MyRect extends Rectangle {}
```

Or

```
class MyRect extends CustomNode {
    override function create() {Rectangle{x:30 y:30 width:10 height:10}}
}
```

It gives me the following runtime error

```
Type 'javafxapplication1.NumberGrid$MyRect' not found.
```

Where of course `javafxapplication1.NumberGrid` are the package and file the `MyRect` class is in.

This guy at [Sun's forums](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5391083) had the same problem, but I don't see any answer in there.

Or maybe I'm doing that the wrong way, and there's a better approach for duplicating custom nodes?

**update:** Trying to duplicate `Group` worked, but trying to duplicate `Stack` yields the same error.

According to the documentation, it's supposed to support all types supported in `FXD` including `Node`, but maybe it supports only some of `Node`'s descendants?

Comment: No answer but http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=932&threadID=5406575 is related, at least for the Stack remark.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question, but did you try the following?

```
public class MyRect extends CustomNode, Cloneable {

    override public function clone(): MyRect {
        super.clone() as MyRect;
    }
    ...    
}
```

Which works for me via

```
var newRect = rect.clone();
```

Which is not a deep copy (but in my case I didn't need this)